# API not recognizing key and cert extracted from .pfx file

Tags: api, rest, python-requests, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to use this site's API to pull data: https://broker.usaspending.gov/#/login. Would be easy but the log-in is giving me problems. They sent me a .pfx file with my certificate. I extracted the key and cert as a pem and attempted to pass using request. It is not working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from OpenSSL import crypto
import os
import requests
import re

# Extracting certificate & key from the .pfx file 
with open("C:/Users/MBS/TheFolder_Ms/MAX_API/OMBMaxCertificate.pfx", "rb") as file:
    p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(file.read(), b'password')


# I'm converting to PEM because I got the impression I needed to do this from the
# internet
# PEM formatted private key
print (crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
# This returns a byte object; .decode('utf-8') turns it into a string
pem_key1 = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()).decode("utf-8")

# Removing new line characters (\n); thought maybe they were the problem;
# I tried with and without the \n characters
pem_key = "".join(pem_key1.splitlines())

# PEM formatted certificate
print (crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
pem_cert1 = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()).decode("utf-8")

# Removing new line characters (\n)
pem_cert = "".join(pem_cert1.splitlines())

# POST to MAX API

desired_payload = '''{"cert": pem_cert1, "key": pem_key1}'''
url = 'https://serviceauth.max.gov/cas-cert/login?service=https://broker-api.usaspending.gov'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

stuff_use = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = desired_payload)
```

Here's a example of what the pem_key variables look like:

```
pem_key
Out[38]: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCs7PuRbkUemKKMZFUXjw0lPPgjPg6RzgoYpECcCNrs79sK4cf4biZkqfJxwOB7HCt4MiiKegyrqkEjU9X45w/8dJXojX+LLcemUCSTvqX1pE4Xi1HOSp/9IL5017p/GZnDPyLPMTin7jwd0N6aUjP5PTWn4m6vKmOLeztgJtoqX6HxqLQKBgQC6BaO7ATKfEyHIwO1dtj1yFMqZHfPCQiOzzhuCK6jN8xsC5dtSulSRkG8q7awWfFYQNhHVh9MIbhoO8pMDxL/VuMgGWI2CBEIUoOHpmEeR2CDzO/04aR3BoFuObN3xwCVRhFP1b4Kb/IaDdC7FehsBj4U6DzIaQpIMJuDDG6M4fw==-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'

pem_key1
Out[39]: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCs7PuRbkUemKKM\nZFUXjw0lPPgjPg6RzgoYpECcCNrs79sK4cf4biZkqfJxwOB7HCt4MiiKegyrqkEj\nU9X45w/8dJXojX+LLBlqTVw5P4uKcDxRMU1MPvY23onnXGVmrBLExoiIN9yskhBR\nxuht5MUteI0XiW2xYynZD2096V7jvi1EhVIwoXZX6u4bW3I+tdm1v810GwL0KB0h\nO2q8a0mnlHEKuXvZ1SZWel7GXdIjEadGj1yFMqZHfPCQiOzzhuCK6jN8xsC5dtSulSRkG8q7awWfFYQNhHVh9MIbhoO8pMD\nxL/VuMgGWI2CBEIUoOHpmEeR2CDzO/04aR3BoFuObN3xwCVRhFP1b4Kb/IaDdC7F\nehsBj4U6DzIaQpIMJuDDG6M4fw==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
```

The code works and I get no errors.

The site just tells me something is wrong:

```
           This endpoint supports server certificate authentication only.  You may be seeing this message because:<p></p>
<ul>
<li>The application or web site you are trying to access
               is misconfigured.</li>
<li>You are using an old bookmark for PIV/CAC login to MAX.gov.</li>
<li>Your PIV/CAC is not in the card reader, or your browser is not reading it..</li>
<li>Your server certificate is invalid, or your server's UA did not present a certificate.</li>
</ul>
</div></div></div></div></main></body></html>
<h2>What To Do Next</h2>
<p>
<ul>
<li>Let's try to log in again.  Make sure your PIV/CAC is plugged in and <a href="https://broker-api.usaspending.gov?ticket=YOU_SHALL_NOT_PASS">click here to continue</a>.</li>
```

Comment: Please anyone offer some guidance--any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. I placed the pem_cert1 and pem_key1 values returned from above into notepad and saved as a .pem file. This file is named cert_test_this_works2.pem. I then run the following code and it returns the desired result. Hopefully this will help someone in the future who is trying to interact with the DATA Act Broker site.

```
url = 'https://serviceauth.max.gov/cas-cert/login?service=https://broker-api.usaspending.gov'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

stuff_use = requests.get(url, verify = False, cert = 'C:/Users/MBS/TheFolder_MS/MAX_API/key_cert_Dec2/cert_test_this_works2.pem')
```